# SQL which checks, how often a date of an order has changed

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I want to build a SQL code, which shows how often the date of an order has changed over time. Our data set is this following table:

[image: sql table]

In words I want to:

- check between "Time = 1" and "Time = 2" of Material "1299190" -> isDateEqual? If no, then 0, else then 1
- check between "Time = 2" and "Time = 3" of Material "1299190" -> isDateEqual? If no, then 0, else then 1
- check between "Time = 3" and "Time = 4" of Material "1299190" -> isDateEqual? If no, then 0, else then 1

= At the end, it should show, that the date has changed one time

I already tried to build a solution.

I hope you guys and girls can help me with this problem.

with best regards,
M

Comment: Please provide what database systems are you using

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some kind of gaps-and-island problem. Assuming that your RDBMS supports window functions, you can solve it with `lag()` and a `sum()`:

```
select
    Auftrag,
    sum(case when BasicStart != lagBasicStart then 1 else 0 end) changeCount
from (
    select
        t.*,
        lag(BasicStart) over(partition by Auftrag order by time) lagBasicStart
    from mytable
) t
group by Auftrag
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your questions and the SQL can vary a bit from one database to another. You should put what you have tried. Here is a possible solution from what I have understood:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table
WHERE auftrag = x
AND time <= y AND time >= z
ADN bereistellung = basicstart;
```